# lie groups and topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lie-groups

Is there a relationship between Lie groups and topology and is there a succinct explanation that can be provided? Is there a good online reference that discusses this.

Comment: Textbooks on equivariant homotopy theory, symmetry, etc, would be a start.

Comment: A similar discussion http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42249/how-do-lie-groups-classify-geometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Lie groups form an important class of examples of topological spaces with interesting topological properties. One famous example is [Bott periodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem), which is a calculation of the stable homotopy groups of certain classes of Lie groups.

Answer (score 0):

One could define the vast topic of "functional analysis" to be about topological spaces that also have an algebraic structure, such that there is a relation like "certain algebraic operations are continuous". Lie groups are an example of this, they combine a topological structure (being a topological manifold) with an algebraic structure (being a group) such that the group operations are continuous.

This simple relation already has profound implications, one of which has been the topic of [Hilbert's fifth problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem).

Comment: Don´t you mean "Lie groups are an example of this, they combine a topological structure (being a smooth manifold) with an algebraic structure (being a group) such that the group operations are smooth."? Otherwise we would be simply talking about topological groups.